# httpd reload as second command in bash fails

Tags: apache-2.2, bash, centos6, command-line-interface, shell

I am trying to run a command that carries out one action, to renew a certificate, and then reloads Apache.

To do this I am running the following:

```
sudo /home/ec2-user/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto --config 
/home/ec2-user/letsencrypt/cert.ini certonly --debug 
&& service httpd reload
```

Which gives me the following:

```
Updating letsencrypt and virtual environment dependencies......
Requesting root privileges to run with virtualenv:  /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt --config /home/ec2-user/letsencrypt/secure_textinconfidence_com.ini certonly --debug
Version: 1.1-20080819
Version: 1.1-20080819

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/secure.textinconfidence.com/fullchain.pem.
   Your cert will expire on 2016-05-03. To obtain a new version of the
   certificate in the future, simply run Let's Encrypt again.
 - If you like Let's Encrypt, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le

Reloading httpd: not reloading due to configuration syntax error
                                                   [FAILED]
```

However when I run:

```
sudo service httpd configtest
```

I get:

```
Syntax OK
```

Is there something wrong with my command when combining with the cert renewal?

Comment: Please have a look with the logs  _/var/log/httpd/error_log_ and _syslog_ and share output here.

Comment: I re-ran the command and then checked the logs. There is nothing in any of the log files for the time so nothing to share.

Comment: Then try to start service directly  _/etc/init.d/httpd restart_ and check log or output here.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives exactly the same error.

Comment: what happens if you `sudo service httpd reload` without the LE stuff?  I'm wondering if the shell is interpreting the `&&` part without sudo.  You might need to `sudo` twice.

Comment: Bingo! @chicks adding sudo sorted that issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @chicks the shell is interpreting the && part without sudo so doing:

```
sudo /home/ec2-user/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto --config 
/home/ec2-user/letsencrypt/cert.ini certonly --debug 
&& sudo service httpd reload
```

Sorts the problem

Comment: NIcely done sir.